# Collection View Header not showing up

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am trying to add a header to `UICollectionView`. I used storyboard and checked Section Header. A new cell appeared and I am trying to add content to it (A label with some text). The issue is I can see the label in the storyboard but it does not appear in runtime.

In order to make sure that header is showing up, I changed the background color to yellow and I was able to see yellow header in runtime. Still no label.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can reference from this link... http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the fix. I was calling `registerClass:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:` in `viewDidLoad`.

When using storyboards, registration is done internally and the above call was messing things up. Deleting the line of code fixed the problem.

Comment: You're a hero.      .